# HTML Rendering - chrome renders clear: both different on tablets and on desktop

Tags: html, google-chrome, tablet, html-rendering

```
<br style="clear: both">
```

puts about 1em empty space (looks like paragraph start) on tablets  (Chrome, Android tablet) and that behavior is not seen on desktop (in a production website).

What could be underlying reasons for that?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that if you want tablet version to look like desktop version this will solve the problem:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" >
```